# How do I repair screw holes in a brick wall?

Tags: repair, walls, brick, screws, patch

I have screw holes which were put in to support a curtain rail. The curtain's been pulled out a few times by accident, and now the screw holes are crumbling and I don't know how to repair that portion of the wall.

I want to get it firm again, then re-drill and put the rail back up. It's a plastered brick wall.

What should I do to repair the crumbling holes in the wall caused by the dislodged screws?

Comment: What kind of wall do you have?  Is it dot and dab plasterboard (i.e. is there a space between the plaster and the masonry)?

Answer (score 5):

There are [epoxy](http://www.rotdoctor.com/) repair systems for wood. It should work here too. Once it hardens, the epoxy is a tough, sandable, paintable medium that can de drilled. Make sure it keys properly into the hole, so that it does not just pull free under load. This may involve an undercut if necessary.

In fact, I just checked, and there are epoxies available specifically for masonry repair too, but the wood product should be sufficient here, and is easily found in most home stores.

An alternative might be to add a flat wood molding behind the entire length of rod. 3/8 of an inch thick should be sufficient. Paint to match the wall. Now anchor the curtain rod to the wood, using expanding drywall anchors, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the easiest solution is to use filler on the holes and plaster work to get a smooth finish and then drill new holes somewhere else.

Obviously you haven't got much choice if you're putting up a curtain rail.

Another solution might be to screw a wooden board to the wall and then screw the curtain rail to that. You can choose where you fix the board and then you've got something solid to screw the rail to.

You can either paint it the same colour as the wall to blend in, or the same colour as the window to make it look like a part of that.

Answer (score 0):

To repair the holes purchase a small container of non shrinking spackle paste, surgical or particle mask, safety glasses, 150 grade sandpaper, Masonry drill bit that is just smaller than your masonry wall anchor, 4 inch plaster knife, plaster weld, a disposable chipper brush 1".
Remove any loose plaster by scraping with a sturdy putty knife or painters 5 way tool also known as a five in one ( be sure to wear your dust mask and safety glasses.

Once you've removed all loose plaster you should vacuum holes and apply plaster weld to any areas where the plaster or structolite is visible, when the plaster weld liquid has set up you can then apply the spackle paste and be sure to push the spackle paste in as far as possible into the screw holes.

In many cases two coats of spackling paste is needed, let the 1st coat dry completely (2 or 3 hours) before applying second coat. once the spackle has dried and cured you may sand spackle smooth and be sure to vacuum the dust with a good hepa filter shop vac. when rehanging your curtains you should mark your holes with a pencil making sure your holes are level on the opposite side-  you can drill your new pilot holes and insert your masonry wall anchors after.

One last but important note: if your home was built before 1980 it would be a good idea to call in a professional or take a lead tester to the area being attempting any work.