# What is the safest way to fix a curtain rail?

Tags: repair, curtain-rail

What is the safest way to secure a curtain rail? It is sloping on one side and could fall.

Comment: If you're trying to re-secure it to the wall, this answer may help: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/repair-curtain-rod-anchor-ripped-out-of-wall (deals with a curtain rod that was ripped out, but the fix would be similar for you).

Comment: It's a similar question but the circumstances are different. In short, the bracket has not come out of the wall. I may bolster the poll with a central bracket first.

Comment: Can you clarify your question then? Was it not put up straight to being with? Has a bracket bent or something? Is it pulling out of the wall?

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution would be to take the curtain rail down completely and re fix it.

Fill in the existing holes and repaint the wall if necessary then put it back up as if it were new.

You'll need to avoid the existing holes and some of the answers to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/repair-curtain-rod-anchor-ripped-out-of-wall) may be of use.